# I can't update new mentions (tweepy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy, python-module

My bot doesn't reply to new mentions, it keeps seeing ones he has already replied to.

Whenever I run my this code, the while loop keeps going (it's an infinite loop) and when I add new mentions it doesn't update.

What should I do? I already tried `mentions.clear()`, but it didn't help.

```
import tweepy
import time
from pprint import pprint

def get_already_responded(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as file:
        seen = set()

        for line in file:
            seen.add(line.strip())
    return seen

def add_already_responded(responded_id, file_name):
    with open(file_name, "w") as file:
        file.write(str(responded_id) + "\n")


FILE = 'responded.txt'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('removed', 'removed')
auth.set_access_token('removed-removed',
                      'removed')

api = tweepy.API(auth)

mentions = api.mentions_timeline()

# necessary: id, user, text
"""dict_keys(
['_api', '_json', 'created_at', 'id', 'id_str', 'text', 'truncated', 'entities', 'source', 'source_url', 'in_reply_to_status_id', 'in_reply_to_status_id_str', 'in_reply_to_user_id',
 'in_reply_to_user_id_str', 'in_reply_to_screen_name', 'author', 'user', 'geo', 'coordinates', 'place', 'contributors',
  'is_quote_status', 'retweet_count', 'favorite_count', 'favorited', 'retweeted', 'possibly_sensitive', 'lang']
)
"""


while True:
    seen = get_already_responded(FILE)
    for mention in mentions:
        userScreenName = mention.user.screen_name
        tweetId = mention.id
        textMsg = mention.text.split()[1:]

        print(f'{userScreenName} - {tweetId} --> {textMsg}')

        try:
            if tweetId not in seen:
                api.update_status(status=f"@{userScreenName} ur msg ---> {textMsg}", in_reply_to_status_id=tweetId)
                seen.add(tweetId)
        except tweepy.error.TweepError:
            add_already_responded(tweetId, FILE)
```

Comment: Do you know why your loop is infinite? When do you expect it to exit ? `while True:` has no exit-condition.

Comment: @hc_dev what do u suggest? Should I put **seen(set)** after except or what ?